# SQL server interview query on index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got one interview question from NET but didn't find the proper solution can anyone tell 
me what's wrong with this query?

Given this table structure and index, what is the problem with the subsequent query?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.IndexQ (
ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
TestBit bit NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INEX IX_IndexQ_TestBit ON dbo.IndexQ (TestBit)
GO

* Insert some rows where some bits are 0 and some are 1...

SELECT *
FROM dbo.IndexQ
WHERE TestBit = 1
* What's the problem with this query?
```

Comment: On a side note, its not efficient to have an `index` on `low cardinality columns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the problem in your NONCLUSTERED index on bit field. If you have a large table, you should not build index on bit field, because then more records it has, them less effective you index will work, but more date you will use on it.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server

Comment: If possible can you explain in deep.

Comment: @Luv well, the index itself is useful (in most cases) when you have various values. It avoids you from full table scan, replacing it by index tables scan, which is faster, because these tables are smaller in several times. Their size depends on the column values and their vary. In case of bit field SQL will have only two values, and it would cost almost the same to make a table search, other than bit   index table. On the other hand this index will store unnesessary pointers, which would cost you some of your space

Comment: @Luv such index could be useful if OP would have TestBit allowing NULLs, or if TestBit would store a values of some kind acomplishment - new values would be 0, but after some time they become 1, and most values will always be 1. But in case of 50%-%50 it will be unprofitable

Comment: Adding to what @voo has suggested ,generally selectivity of columns is considered for determining the index which is equal to `Selectivity=Unique Value/No of rows` .So in case of `bit` column unique values is 2 and if no of rows is `1000` then `Selectivity is 2%` which means for every search `500` records will come back provided having equal distribution of data

Comment: @praveen: Yes, but the selectivity is not the only problem here. The second problem is that this SELECT query must return all (values) columns.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: Yup your are right .Since `Select *` is used therefore it forces `Table Scan` .But `Table Scan ` are genarelly faster for the query optimiser to scan through each row and return them than lookup each row in an index .If its a relativily small table than `Table Scan` are not a problem but for large tables definately the Op's query will pose problem

Comment: @praveen: (1) Table Scan faster than Seek: it depends. (2) If `dbo.IndexQ` table is small **(ex. one page of rows = 8K)** then the data type and the selectivity of `TestBit` column are *less* important.

Comment: @voo: That index will be effective (Seek) for queries like this: `SELECT TestBit FROM dbo.IndexQ WHERE TestBit = <constant>`. So, your answer is not complet.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Well, I expect that OP's interviewers assumed to have a  table to grow in future. And my answer says "If you have a large table". As for the current state, you are right on 100% - the index would not be used